# Дана строка. Заменить первые буквы всех слов на заглавные (если слово начинается с заглавной буквы, оставить без изменения)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    char str[80] = "hellho word heh HAW HheH wa", *ptr;

    cout << str << endl;

    //Получаю 1-ое слово как строку.
    ptr = strtok(str, " ");

    do {
        if (*ptr == tolower(*ptr))
            *ptr = toupper(*ptr);

        cout << ptr << ' ';
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    } while (ptr);

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решил задачу немного не так как нужно, на мой взгляд. Можно считать задачу решённой?

Comment: Я бы не считал задачу решённой, т. к. `strtok` модифицирует исходную строку. Если вы выведете исходную строку через `cout`, вы получите только часть. Можно, например, вернуть пробелы на место :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что считать правильным решением. И смотря что считать словом :)
Примем, как у вас - что слово - это нечто, ограниченное пробелами.

Ваше решение дает поток слов, но не сохраняет количество пробелов. Например, `AAA    BBB` превратит в `AAA BBB`. Насколько это критично - вам виднее. Кроме того, ваша исходная строка будет "испорчена", она не будет содержать те же слова, просто с другими первыми буквами. У вас же задача - не вывести слова, а изменить их **в строке**, как я понимаю.

Я бы поступил проще - просто сканируем символ за символом, и все символы, следующие после пробела (а также первый символ строки) делаем прописными.

Код сами напишете?

Comment: буду пробовать, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 2):

можно проще, хотя дело вкуса

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Введите слова, разделенные пробелами ";

    string s;

    while( cin >> s ){
        s[ 0 ] = toupper( s[ 0 ] );\\перобразуем
        cout << s << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```